# Compatibility of DDR3 and Intel 4th Generation Processors

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr3

I have recently come across the concept of DDR3L, and am doing some research. I am coming across some conflicting information..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Specification -> Says that 4th Generation Intel CPUs for laptops are NOT compatible with 1.5v DDR3 and can only use DDR3L.

I have a laptop with [intel I7 4700MQ](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75117/intel-core-i7-4700mq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html) and its spec sheet agrees that it only supports DDR3L memory.

However when I check CPU-Z for said machine, atleast 2 of the 3 sticks of memory say Voltage 1.5V in the last line of SPD, and these are the 2 sticks the laptop came with. The part number(10281763) leads to [this ram stick](https://www.memorybenchmark.net/ram.php?ram=A-DATA+Technology+10281763+4GB&id=3633) which is explicitly PC3 and NOT PC3L (so DDR3). The 3rd stick that I bought later was DDR3L (I didnt look for it specifically at the time, thankfully it worked), and that says 1.35V ( I presume then that CPU-Z is indicating here that it is DDR3L, even if it might be running in 1.5v mode.

How come my laptop is using what appears to be DDR3 ram while all documentation says it should not be able to.

Comment: What is the part number on your A-DATA modules?  The reference site indicates they memory was first benchmarked in 1970.  I suspect we have a case of that particular website having inaccurate information about the module.  **`10281763` isn't the part number.**  I have deleted my answer for the time being until I have all the information.

Comment: That is the part number according to CPU Z

Comment: What does the label say on the module?  I have looked for `10281763` was unable to find any actual specification page on that module.